# uv map not visible in object mode

Tags: modeling

Here's what I hope is a simple question.

I have a mesh with a wood texture map and a bevel modifier. The woodblock displayed correctly using the cycles render engine.

The trouble came when I added a remesh modifier then the block displyed correctly in edit mode but not in object mode or when I rendered it.

Please disregard the bad placement of the map  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/klm6s.jpg)[image]

Comment: Can you post a .blend file to look at?

Comment: Remesh modifier changes the topology of the original mesh. This change can be significant or insignificant depending on the settings you chose. If the UV map looks mangled after using this modifier, then you either have to change the settings to better fit the original mesh or redo the UV map after applying the modifier so it fits better.

Comment: I'm not sure how to post the blender file. I forgot to mention I'm using 2.8

Comment: I went back and tried to add the uv map again but it didn't work.

Comment: I also wanted to add a shot of the object in the object mode but it didn't allow me to post 2 pictures. The object mode and rendered image shows the block as hust solid brown without the grain